# Pass variables (GET or POST) through the entire lifecycle of Jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I have a fresh Laravel 8 project with the Jetstream installation working fine.

I have an app that launches a query (`GET`) to my login route with two variables for various needs. Unfortunately, I need to treat these variables once the user has managed to log in, and I don't know how many places I have to pass them through (routes, controllers, views, middleware, etc.).

I cannot use `$_SESSION` variables because the traffic is filtered by a Router (the one in charge of making the request to the webserver) and always has the same identifier (although the variables passed are different in each request). Any suggestions?

Comment: WRITING IN ALL CAPITALS LOOKS LIKE SHOUTING SO YOU MIGHT WANT TO AVOID THAT

Comment: Just because a request is passed through a router doesn't mean it can't use sessions. You may want to double-check the setup if sessions are shared between devices and browsers.

Comment: The router is a captive portal and it is the one in charge of making the request, not the users

Comment: Session is actually controlled through the use of cookies. When you log into a web app via browser you'll likely receive a cookie in the response which contains the session ID. The browser then automatically passes this session ID back to the server every time it makes a request, a bit like a token. There's no reason in theory why any automated code cannot do the same - first it must obtain the session cookie by making a request to the login endpoint and submitting valid credentials, and then it can store and use the cookie value in subsequent requests

Comment: Alternatively if you're trying to make an API which is intended to be accessed by applications or other automated processes (rather than a browser) then most APIs employ stateless authentication using token-based auth - first you call a token endpoint to get a time-limited auth token, then you pass the token in every subsequent request to the API, to identify yourself. Actually quite similar to the sessions concept, but without cookies, and with entirely stateless management of it on the server side. People often implement the OAuth2.0 standard to provice such functionality.

Comment: I have a Wi-Fi router for my clients that as soon as they are connected does not allow them to surf the Internet, it only allows access to my web server. My router is responsible for saving the ip, mac, device type, among other things, and encrypting it in AES-256-CBC. Create the GET Request and pass my client data to it. Once they reach my server, I need the client to log in and once logged in, create a list in a directory that I retrieve through a POST request on my router. Facing the server, only my router connects and makes requests.

Comment: Well then you'll need to program your router to do what I've described, or if that proves to be impossible, find an alternative approach such as employing another intermediate server or application between the router and your app, to do the task

Comment: Is it impossible to pass the variables through the different routes?

Comment: You have a variable that you want to pass to your front-end; like a flash session message. If it is there then front-end will have it else not. E.g a session flash 'User Created' ??